# Can I add a snapshot in between the histroy and the current block? EOSio

Tags: nodeos, full-node

My node is syncing very slow.
If I try to start the node from the latest snapshot to sync with node and add previous snapshot later, will this work?

Will it resolve the histroy issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshot doesn't have any history. (History here means blocks and transactions) It only contains the latest state, and you can sync blocks from the block where snapshot was generated. If you need past blocks (eg. for making a query about transactions before snapshot generation), you need complete blocks.log. However, you can use snapshot to build the latest state instead of replaying all transactions from genesis.

Mixing multiple snapshots is not supported and has no meaning. (Multiple snapshots mean states in different time point)

Comment: Thank you @conr2d for the detailed explanation. Can you please add a reference for the block.log? I am finding a block.log from genesis to the nearest latest block, but unfortunately unable to find any lead.

Comment: There were some sites providing download of blocks.log, but it seems they are all closed because of cost. If I find one, I will leave the link here.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.